# What ebook formats does iBooks support?

Tags: books

What file formats of ebooks does iBooks support?

Answer (score 9):

It supports `ePub` and `PDF` formats. 
To import those formats you will need to add the ebook to iTunes and then either select automatic synchronization or drag them across manually and they will be added to your iBooks on the next sync.
If you have Dropbox for iOS you can also add files directly to iBooks from there.

Answer (score 3):

iBooks supports the ePub file format, iBooks Author books, PDFs, MP3 audiobooks, AAC audiobooks, and Audible.com audiobooks.